# How to skip failures and continue with run when playing multiple ansible playbooks at once?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I am running multiple ansible playbooks for test automation in one of my projects. The problem is, test (containing multiple playbooks) aborts if even one task (in one playbook) get failed.

Is there any way to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You can set `ignore_errors: yes`. This can be set for certain tasks or the whole playbook.

```
- hosts: all
  ignore_errors: yes
  roles: ...
```

Comment: Thanks! We don't want to use ignore_errors as it will proceed with other tasks in same playbook. Actually, I am running multiple playbook at once and need is to skip the playbook on failure and proceed with next playbook execution.

Comment: I don't think this is possible with Ansible. Isn't it an option then to simply run each playbook separately in multiple ansible_playbook runs?

Comment: Ok ! It is required for Jenkins integration, So we might not have control over execution one by one when test case count is huge.